# Change Title Element in a List to Title Case in Python

Tags: python, list, title

```
f = open('database.txt','r')
data_set = ""
while 1:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:break
    data_set += line

print(data_set)
print()
I need to change the Title instances in the database to title case
```

Code so far, I will provide the list in the comments as I was having trouble adding to here

```
file = open("database.txt", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()

data_set = [line.split(' , ') for line in open ("database.txt")]
print (data_set)

for i in range(len(data_set[0])):
    data_set[0][i]=s[i].t()
    print(data_set)
```

converted the database to a list in the above code:[['ID=j234hg\n'], ['Date=19 October 1969\n'], ['Title=court scene with cardinal richelieu\n'], ['ID=d45j5jkd\n'], ['Date=28 December 1969\n'], ['Title=THE ROYAL PHILHARMONIC ORCHESTRA GOES TO THE BATHROOM\n'], ['ID=s4k5jk\n'], ['Date=8 December 1970\n'], ['Title=crossing the atlantic on a tricycle\n'], ['ID=zd7u4h\n'], ['Date=19 October 1969\n'], ['Title=Bicycle Repair Man\n'], ['ID=f983\n'], ['Date=22 December 1970\n'], ['Title=Royal Episode 13 (or: The Queen Will Be Watching)\n'], ['ID=j8s74\n'], ['Date=15 September 1970\n'], ['Title=THE SEMAPHORE VERSION OF WUTHERING HEIGHTS\n'], ['ID=n4j6l3j\n'], ['Date=7 December 1972\n'], ['Title=Mr. Pither']]

Comment: in the list I want to find the title and convert it to titlecase

Comment: can you show us what a line in database.txt looks like? I think you're doing some superfluous processing here. Also does this data live in some database that you might be able to read directly?

Comment: I probably am I am a beginner in python

Comment: the database file looks like this:ID=j234hg
Date=19 October 1969
Title=court scene with cardinal richelieu
ID=d45j5jkd
Date=28 December 1969
Title=THE ROYAL PHILHARMONIC ORCHESTRA GOES TO THE BATHROOM
ID=s4k5jk
Date=8 December 1970
Title=crossing the atlantic on a tricycle
ID=zd7u4h
Date=19 October 1969
Title=Bicycle Repair Man
ID=f983
Date=22 December 1970
Title=Royal Episode 13 (or: The Queen Will Be Watching)
ID=j8s74
Date=15 September 1970
Title=THE SEMAPHORE VERSION OF WUTHERING HEIGHTS
ID=n4j6l3j
Date=7 December 1972
Title=Mr. Pither

Comment: and I converted it into a list to try an change the Titles to titlecase

Answer (score 0):

iterate through the data_set and get texts after 'Title='and use str.title()!

```
data_set = [['ID=j234hg\n'], ['Date=19 October 1969\n'], ['Title=court scene with cardinal richelieu\n'], ['ID=d45j5jkd\n'], ['Date=28 December 1969\n'], ['Title=THE ROYAL PHILHARMONIC ORCHESTRA GOES TO THE BATHROOM\n'], ['ID=s4k5jk\n'], ['Date=8 December 1970\n'], ['Title=crossing the atlantic on a tricycle\n'], ['ID=zd7u4h\n'], ['Date=19 October 1969\n'], ['Title=Bicycle Repair Man\n'], ['ID=f983\n'], ['Date=22 December 1970\n'], ['Title=Royal Episode 13 (or: The Queen Will Be Watching)\n'], ['ID=j8s74\n'], ['Date=15 September 1970\n'], ['Title=THE SEMAPHORE VERSION OF WUTHERING HEIGHTS\n'], ['ID=n4j6l3j\n'], ['Date=7 December 1972\n'], ['Title=Mr. Pither']]

for index,l in enumerate(data_set):
    column_name,value = l[0].split("=")
    if 'Title' == column_name:
        data_set[index]="=".join([column_name+value.title()])

print data_set
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data_set = [['ID=j234hg\n'], ['Date=19 October 1969\n'], ['Title=court scene with cardinal richelieu\n'], ['ID=d45j5jkd\n'], ['Date=28 December 1969\n'], ['Title=THE ROYAL PHILHARMONIC ORCHESTRA GOES TO THE BATHROOM\n'], ['ID=s4k5jk\n'], ['Date=8 December 1970\n'], ['Title=crossing the atlantic on a tricycle\n'], ['ID=zd7u4h\n'], ['Date=19 October 1969\n'], ['Title=Bicycle Repair Man\n'], ['ID=f983\n'], ['Date=22 December 1970\n'], ['Title=Royal Episode 13 (or: The Queen Will Be Watching)\n'], ['ID=j8s74\n'], ['Date=15 September 1970\n'], ['Title=THE SEMAPHORE VERSION OF WUTHERING HEIGHTS\n'], ['ID=n4j6l3j\n'], ['Date=7 December 1972\n'], ['Title=Mr. Pither']]



for index,l in enumerate(data_set):
    if 'Title=' == l[0][:6]:
        data_set[index]="Title="+l[0][6:].title()

print data_set
```

Comment: if you find an answer to your questions, either accept it or up vote! that should do. you need not post the same answer again! Thanks.